# Update object in array of objects

Tags: powershell

I am creating an array of objects through iteration. Some of the Objects are redundant and for those I just want to update one property or alternatively merge them after the array is created (though i don't think that's the better solution)

I need this array as a csv in the end

```
foreach ( $Group in $groups) {
    $groupmembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group
    $group = Get-ADGroup -Identity $adobeGroup -properties Description
    $description = $group.description
    $i = 0 
    foreach ($member in $groupmembers) {
        if ($member.objectClass -eq "user") {
            $User = get-aduser -filter 'name -eq $member.name' -properties C, mail 
            if ($i -eq 0) {
                $Users += @(
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        'Username'                            = $User.mail
                        'Email'                               = $User.mail
                        "Country"                             = $User.C
                        "Product Configurations"              = $description
                    }  
                )
            }
            else {
                if ($Users.Username.Contains($User.mail)) {
                    $changeme = $Users | where-object { $_.Username -eq $User.Username } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Product Configurations"
                    $changeme += ", " + $description
                }
                else {
                    $Users += @(
                        [pscustomobject]@{
                            'Username'                            = $User.mail
                            'Email'                               = $User.mail
                            "Country"                             = $User.C
                            "Product Configurations"              = $description
                        }  
                    )
                }            
            }
        }
        $i++
    }
}
```

I expect

```
if ($Users.Username.Contains($User.mail)) {
                    $changeme = $Users | where-object { $_.Username -eq $User.Username } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Product Configurations"
                    $changeme += ", " + $description
                }
```

to update "Product Configurations" from "description1" to "descrption1, description2" if I have iterated over this User before.  The actual result is that "Product Configurations" stays the same. 
This has nothing to do with the actual Question but I get an error message if I don't do the if $i-eq 0 statement since the object hasn't been created yet and the second if statement doesn't make no sense then. This looks pretty ugly to me. Do you have a suggestion for a better solution?

Comment: `'name -eq $member.name'` won't work as intended (it's a literal string). Use an ordered hashtable to collect the entries, keyed by username, which allows you to locate an existing entry much more efficiently.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in editing. This wasn't the statement I meant. This actually works well to select the Userobjects.

Comment: Do not assign it to a variable like `$changeme`, just directly pipe it to a `ForEach-Object` and change the current item (`$_`) knowing that it should be unique anyways: `$Users | where-object {$_.Username -eq $User.Username} | ForEach-Object {$_.'Product Configurations' += ", " + $description}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$changeme` is a *string* variable whose content you're updating. It doesn't refer to  and therefore doesn't update the *property*  on the user object.

Instead, you must obtain the user object and update its `.'Product Configurations'` property.

```
# Important: Initialize the $Users array, so you can 
#            later add [pscustomobject] instances one by one without having to
#            wrap them in an array.
$Users = @()

# ...

if ($userToChange = $Users | Where-Object { $_.Username -eq $User.mail }) {
  $userToChange.'Product Configurations' += ", " + $description
} else {
  $Users += [pscustomobject] @{
    Username                            = $User.mail
    Email                               = $User.mail
    Country                             = $User.C
    'Product Configurations'            = $description
  }  
}
```

Note that I've streamlined the code for finding an existing element.
In PSv4+ you could make that more efficient with `$Users.Where({ $_.Username -eq $User.mail }, 'First')`

A few asides:

- If you used an (ordered) hashtable to build your collection of custom objects, keyed by username, you could locate an existing entry much more efficiently.
- I wouldn't expect `-Filter 'name -eq $member.name'` to work, because embedding variable references in literal filters works only with simple variable references, not with property access such as `.name`.
- Building an array with `+=` is inefficient, because a new array has to be created behind the scenes every time an element is added.